# Accessing multiple form values with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I access multiple updated form values with jquery?

I have a jsp form with textboxes that show saved values. When these values are updated, I need to access the updated values. The jsp textboxes are as follows:

```
<html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.pastAmt" onchange="showInfo();" />
<html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.currAmt" onchange="showInfo();" />
```

In the showInfo function, I need to access the values for both user.pastAmt and user.currAmt, regardless of where the onchange event is triggered from:

```
function showInfo() {
   alert('pastAmt: ' + $("[name='user.pastAmt']").val());
   alert('currAmt: ' + $("[name='user.currAmt']").val());
}
```

The problem is that if I access it as above, I only show the saved values, and not the updated values.

I've found that I can send one of the updated values from the event using a "this" keyword:

```
<html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.pastAmt" onchange="showInfo(this);" />
<html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.currAmt" />
```

With:

```
function showInfo(pastA) {
   alert('pastAmt: ' + $(pastA).val());
   alert('currAmt: ' + $("[name='user.currAmt']").val());
}
```

But how do I access the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, use a jQuery even listener for each one.  You can combine them if you can select both in one jQuery selector.

```
$("[name='user.currAmt']").on('change', function () {
    var result = $("[name='user.currAmt']").val();
});
$("[name='user.pastAmt']").on('change', function () {
    var result = $("[name='user.currAmt']").val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's enough to get me going again!